# Is the definition of a proposition a true proposition itself?

Tags: logic

A proposition is a statement that is either true or false.

Is this 1. a statement 2. true?

If so, is there any issue here? Could this be construed as tautologous or axiomatic?

Comment: **1.** has the structure of a proposition, so, yes (true). **2.** affirms a truth, so it's a tautology (redundant with 1). In order for that to be an axiom, it needs to be part of a [formal system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system).

Comment: @RodolfoAP To a logical pluralist, it is not a tautology.

Comment: No you need a better definition! Any old sentence or a statement is NOT a proposition. A proposition MUST BE literally meaningful AND reflect truth in reality. By true here I mean objectively true. There are different types of TRUTH so that is why I mentioned this. A dictionary definition is not enough! Propositions are not STATEMENTS & they are not SENTENCES to begin with by definition. Only people outside of philosophy would think so. Is the following proposition true: all unicorns are white mammals at least 6 feet tall? To math people the answer is NO. They say there are no unicorns.

Comment: I also want to note that any proposition about Unicorns are not false because well if they are not true then they must be false. This is NOT so! If Unicorns do not exist on Earth then I have the existential import issue. The proposition in this case is NIETHER  true or false --- it would be deemed MEANINGLESS.  So there you have it. Propositions are not limited to just Ttue or False. Some are non truthful. Again non truthful does not mean false.

Comment: No. Definitions are not propositions, they are prescriptions/imperatives: this shall be used to denote that. As such, they cannot be true or false. Once the definition is *made*, a similarly looking expression will be a true statement. For example, 2:=1+1 is neither true nor false, 2=1+1 is then true. And in philosophy, [propositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition) are not statements, they are their "meanings", multiple statements can express the same proposition.

Comment: @Conifold Don't all imperatives "Do X" paraphrase to declarative "I want you to do X"? Is it not true an assignment is nothing more than a truth-bearer where the justification for the claim for truth is simply "Because I say so"? Thus, an inch is defined as a 12th of a foot its still a true proposition, but one by fiat? In fact, isn't a prescriptive definition a performative act with the aim to create consensus around the truth-bearing meaning it describes? And how not contradictory to assert that your definition of definition is true, and one which negates your premise is false?

Comment: @JD On Frege's theory, imperatives have the form "bring about X", where X is a truth-apt statement (propositional content). The command itself is not truth-apt. The justification is given for the imperative force (the source of authority), not truth value. "Inch is defined as..." in typical contexts is not a definition, it is a declarative statement *about* an existing definition, which can be true or false. Same with asserting that some definition is "correct", i. e. is in agreement with the convention. Speech acts concern pragmatics, not semantics.

Comment: @jd, you are conflating the meaning of the imperative with an inference that can sometimes be drawn from someone's expression of the imperative. The plain meaning of an imperative is to impel someone to act; the plain meaning of a proposition is to cause someone to believe something. Speech very often has implied or concealed meanings which differ from the plain meanings, but those are situation-dependent and not part of the meaning of the expression itself.

Comment: @DavidGudeman Thanks, I understand what pragmatism is, and this discussion is about me trying to suss out the notion surrounding determining when an utterance is truth-bearing fact, and when it is a non-truth bearing "definition".

Comment: @jd, at a higher level, what you are doing is essentially a form of reductionism. You are saying: this thing which seems to have its own special character is really something else that doesn't have that character. A reduction is usually interesting because it demonstrates an interesting relationship between the reduced thing and the thing is is reduced to, but it is almost always wrong because there is almost always something about the special character that cannot be accounted for by the thing it is reduced to.

Comment: @Conifold So, you'd accept that a prescriptive definition is an imperative with world-to-mind direction and has no truth value per se, but a descriptive definition is a proposition with mind-to-world fit and bears truth since it respects is-out such that it just an utterance which speaks to the state of affairs? Or do you deny the existence of the general thrust of the SEP article's definition of definition as utterances serving to explain meaning? And what of suggestion of definition neither descriptive nor prescriptive, but consensual?

Comment: @DavidGudeman I'm not concerned with the reduction of definiendum and definiens at all. I respect definition is a type of identity with utility in simplification. I'm asking after the justification for accepting the explanatory power of a definition.

Comment: @DavidGudeman That is to say, that I might accept the claim that a prescriptive definition is strictly speaking performative in so far as the truth-bearing proposition it contains is a subset of it's meaning, but such a dichotomy raises questions of the relationship between agents such that authority itself is a mental construct free to be rejected or negotiated in affecting change in the state of affairs; in the case of definition accepted by consensus or merely determined from observation and empirical methods, it seems to me that definitions still exist as explanatory devices.

Comment: @DavidGudeman That would contradict Conifold's claim "Definitions are not propositions, they are prescriptions/imperatives:" As best as I can tell, according to the author of [SEP's *Definitions*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/definitions/), definitions are not always prescriptions/imperatives. So, I'm seeking his clarification. You're free to weigh in, of course. "Apples are red fruit that grow on trees" is a definition not by prescription, but by description, and it's explanatory force is derived from it's essentialist characteristic, right? No natural-language authority commands here.

Comment: @Conifold Certainly in language acquisition among young children, particularly among ostensive definitions inferred in the third person by the young, there is no manifestation of authority or imperative at all; a child simply observes and mimics the transaction in a pragmatic eagerness to play the language game. Two adults who long ago accepted by convention the definition for 'apple' are engaged in utterance free of imperative, and the child just makes the association and gradually develops the vocabulary to answer 'What is?' Imperative speech acts are a tiny sliver of shared intentionality.

Comment: @jd, you seem to have misunderstood me. I was only talking about this sentence by you: "Don't all imperatives 'Do X' paraphrase to declarative 'I want you to do X'?" I wasn't referring to you linguistic theory of the nature of definitions.

Comment: @DavidGudeman I didn't misunderstand you. I simply found all of your comments beside the point.

Answer (score 3):

The more general definition, which subsumes yours, is that a proposition is a truth bearer- something that bears truth value. If you accept bivalence, then this is equivalent to your definition.

As to your questions, 1. that is certainly a statement, namely, a statement of the english language. 2. If you accept bivalence and a certain notion of proposition, it is true. Further, you can construct a system in which it is an axiom or tautologous, but you can do so with many statements, and just because you can does not mean you should, ie it does not mean it is unqualifiedly true.

For more, see SEP's entry on propositions : https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/propositions/

Answer (score 0):

EDITED 2022-08-22

### Caveat

"Champions of propositions often write as if there was an easy and decisive argument in favor of positing [propositions]." **- pg 137, Szabo and Thomason, *The Philosophy of Language***

"You can find linguists and philosophers who will tell you that it's trivial that propositions exist, and others who will tell you that it's obvious they don't." **- pg 138, Szabo and Thomason, *The Philosophy of Language***

The point of these quotations is that "propositions", are purported to be mental objects, and not all philosophers agree they exist. Propositions, however are at a bare minimum a useful fiction.

A statement is generally taken to mean the medium, utterance, particular, or concrete expression of the dichotomy, and proposition is the message, meaning, universal, or abstract expression of the dichotomy. Why dichotomy? Because there must be some way to resolve synonymy. 'Here am I' and 'I am here' are both synonymically meaningful, yet the first and second are also simultaneously distinct. Thus, philosophers will recognize there are two utterances with one (approximate) meaning.

### Short Answer

1. "A proposition is a statement that is either true or false." is a proposition and a statement.
2. Whether or not the above proposition is true depends on a logical system accepting the [Principle of Bivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_bivalence):

### Long Answer

> In logic, the semantic principle (or law) of bivalence states that every declarative sentence expressing a proposition (of a theory under inspection) has exactly one truth value, either true or false. [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic) A logic satisfying this principle is called a two-valued logic or bivalent logic... In formal logic, the principle of bivalence becomes a property that a semantics may or may not possess.

In [fuzzy logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic), for instance, logic is NOT bivalent, and a proposition can have a real-numbered truth value, hence not only NOT bivalent, but possessing an infinite number of truth values on the continuum between false (0) and true (1).

Alternatively, if one is willing to subscribe to [dialetheism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialetheism), a proposition can be both true and false simultaneously:

> Dialetheism (from Greek δι- di- 'twice' and ἀλήθεια alḗtheia 'truth') is the view that there are statements that are both true and false. More precisely, it is the belief that there can be a true statement whose negation is also true. Such statements are called "true contradictions", dialetheia, or nondualisms.

In regards to the question of a definition in the general case being a proposition, I answer 'yay'. Definitions, as per SEP are explanations of meaning, and as such, in the general case express propositions about said explanations that [correspond to truths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theory_of_truth) in the world or respond to the [coherence of other propositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_theory_of_truth). From SEP:

> Definitions sought by philosophers are not of the sort found in a dictionary. Frege’s definition of number (1884) and Alfred Tarski’s definition of truth (1983, ch. 8) are not offered as candidates for dictionary entries. When an epistemologist seeks a definition of “knowledge,” she is not seeking a good dictionary entry for the word ‘know’. **The philosophical quest for definition can sometimes fruitfully be characterized as a search for an explanation of meaning.** But the sense of ‘explanation of meaning’ here is very different from the sense in which a dictionary explains the meaning of a word.

### Response to Claims about Definitions

It has been asserted as fact that definitions are imperatives without semantic force. In the spirit of pluralism, it should be noted that such a claim isn't a fact, but thesis of an argument favored by neo-Platonic realists. This claim is actually one of three major positions. From the [Encyclopedia of Philosophy's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Encyclopedia_of_Philosophy) entry 'Definitions', Vol. 2, pg. 664:

> All the views of definition that have been proposed can be subsumed under three general types of positions... called "essentialist", "prescriptive", and "linguistic" types..."

From further on, pg. 668:

> [Prescriptive] theories avoid... trouble by denying that definitions are statements of any kind. The prescriptivist assimilates definitions to imperative sentences rather than to declarative sentences and endows them with the function of syntactic or semantic rules...

Thus, the claim found in response to your question that imperatives aren't propositions is a one of several general positions one might take, and NOT a fact, but a thesis.

Comment: A statement is generally taken to mean the medium, utterance, particular, or concrete expression of the dichotomy, and proposition is the message, meaning, universal, or abstract expression of the dichotomy. Why dichotomy? Because there must be some way to resolve synonymy. 'Here am I' and 'I am here' are both synonymically meaningful, yet the first and second are also simultaneously distinct. Thus, philosophers will recognize there are two utterances with one (approximate) meaning.

Comment: -1: This doesn't answer the question but merely lifts it to an example of self-referentiality.

Comment: @MoziburUllah That meaning is in part derived from meaning is self-referential and acceptable. This is due to the fact that meaning is compositional. Non-circularity in providing meaning can come only from non-semantic experience.  This alone is the foundation of meaning in a broader sense.

Comment: Whatever. The point I'm making is that you're not answering the question. Are you saying that you are?

Answer (score 0):

A definition of a proposition is not a proposition itself, it is just that - a definition.

Since propositions are those sentences that carry truth or falsity then a definition of a proposition, being just a definition, cannot carry either. Thus it is neither true nor false. The right question to ask about a definition is not whether it is true or false but whether it helps clarify the subject under discussion and hence useful. It has use-value and not truth-value.

> Could this be construed as tautologous or axiomatic?

No. It cannot be tautologous because it is not a proposition. And nor are definitions axioms and hence it is not axiomatic. Definitions are used, however, in axiomatic systems, but they presuppose the axiomatic system to have been already constructed.

Comment: -1 You claim a definition cannot bear truth and falsity,  but introduce the claim without rationale or source relying instead on faith that definitions cannot be propositions. As you likely know,  Quine dismissed the existence of propositions entirely,  so to characterize a proposition in any manner definitely is an act of faith,  and is anti-philosophical. To define a definition in this way seems to be an authoritarian scam.

Comment: @J D: This is well known and if you can't be bothered to look up these notions for yourself then its not my business to teach you the difference. No, I didn't know that about Quine. But I'm not talkimg about Quine. Nor is the OP. Can you show me where in the OP's post he mentions Quine?

Comment: @J D: And no, I'm not relying on faith to distinguish between definition and proposition but I am relying on your ability - well, I'm not actually - to understand the difference.

Comment: @J D: I get it - you're an athiest. So what? They're ten-a-penny in the world now and nothing special and certainly not the "free-thinkers" that they boast and about themselves. They too have their dogmas as much as any religious cult. What I'm interested here is fairly argued arguments. It is after all a philosophy site where arguments should count for something. Obfuscating the fact that definitions are well known to be what they are - and not propositions - is not just sloppy thinking but dangerous thinking. Its not thought, but appearance of it.

Comment: Actually, I'm just attacking the claim that definitions are imperatives without meaning. I meant faith with a little f, like Camus's Leap, the sort that precipitates philosophical death. It's a thesis, not a given. My disclaimer wasn't for you. It was for people who wandered through and might accidentally believe it's a tenable conclusion.

Comment: @J D: Definitions are imperatives. They are being declared as such. You're perhaps over-thinking or under-thinking things. Take your pick. Camus knew the difference between genuine faith and those of cynical faith and he admired the former whilst contemptuous of the latter. Why otherwise would he call Simone Weil "one of the great spirits of our time"?

Answer (score -1):

Consider the disquotational scheme:

> "A is B," is true if and only if A is B.

Now take that whole scheme and plug it into itself:

> ("A is B," is true if and only if A is B) is true if and only if, "A is B," is true if and only if A is B.

Eventually this will be plenty unwieldy to think through (and check what happens when you try to run the liar sentence through it), but at any rate, a schematic sentence/proposition cannot be particularly true by itself, but only when its variables are cashed out; until then, it might be characterized as "possibly true," "generally true," or what-have-you. For example, consider:

> "The round square is round," is true if and only if the round square is round.

If it is logically or at least "metaphysically" impossible for a square to be a round square, one might object to the whole sentence/proposition as such, such that it is not counted a possibly true instance of the disquotational scheme. But here I verge on the mystery of counterpossible reasoning, which I can't honestly comment more on (having researched the topic only a little, so far).